# Queue not getting removed once consumed?

Tags: java, oracle

I'm using Oracle AQ With below consumer code in Java.

Why the queue still remains in the database. What call do I need to make so that queue will get removed once it is consumed?

```
   QueueConnection myqueue = getConnection();  
   Session session = myqueue.createQueueSession(false,  Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
   myqueue.start();

   queue = ((AQjmsSession) session).getQueue("demo", "myqueue");
   MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(queue);       
   TextMessage msg = (TextMessage) consumer.receive();
   System.out.println("message" + msg.getText());

   consumer.close();
   session.close();
   myqueue.close();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm wrong, but its not the queue that gets consumed, its the messages that go into the queue that get consumed.  The queue is just a table, no?  You could explicitly "DROP TABLE MYQUEUE" once you are sure that no producer or consumer expects it to exist.